# My star rating with checkboxes isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've done this all-client-side star rating. But here's a problem. The background-position doesn't change when I click a star. See, the checkbox background image i have got has an outline-only star and four golden stars. I want the checkbox to change its bg to the first star (golden) when it's checked. I hope you understand:

```js
var onestar = document.getElementById("one-star");
var twostar = document.getElementById("two-star");
var threestar = document.getElementById("three-star");
var fourstar = document.getElementById("four-star");
var fivestar = document.getElementById("five-star");
var onechecked = document.getElementById("one-star").checked = true;
if (onestar.checked = true) {
  this.classList.toggle = "solid";
}
```

```css
label {
  margin: 0;
}

.star-check {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  -o-appearance: none !important;
  -ms-appearance: none !important;
  appearance: none !important;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url('https://www.worthschools.net/userfiles/197/my%20files/4-stars.jpg?id=29736');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.solid {
  background-position: left 0;
}
```

```html
<label>How many stars do you give to this product?</label>
<div class="star-container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="star-check" id="one-star" class="star-check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="star-check" id="two-star" class="star-check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="star-check" id="three-star" class="star-check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="star-check" id="four-star" class="star-check">
  <input type="checkbox" name="star-check" id="five-star" class="star-check">
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the console! ` "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null",` is the error which means it can not find the element. `id="star-check one-star"` is the id..... Makes no sense why the id has a space. Remove `star-check `

Comment: `onestar.checked = true` <-- That is not a comparison.

Comment: Ids can not have space... I believe so... Among other things in this code...

Comment: uh... ok? Ima change the code right now.

Comment: But... can't an element have two id's?

Comment: "But... can't an element have two id's? " => No. But you _can_ have more than one `class`

Comment: So, I've removed my "star-check" id. Still can't make the bg change.

Comment: "But you can have more than one class" => I know, but every time I try (with any given code that's not copied) I fail.

Comment: See this comment `if (onestar.checked = true) {` is not checking if onestar is checked. it should be `if (onestar.checked == true) {` or `if (onestar.checked) {`

Comment: Not working, @Ted

Comment: `this.classList.toggle` -> what is `this` supposed to refer to? Also, isn't `classList.toggle` a function?

Comment: @evolutionxbox 'this' refers to the 'onestar' variable, which at the same time refers to the first star

Comment: Yeah, I'm just pointing you in the right direction. Your code doesn't actually do anything. See the very first comment for starters.

Comment: It's undefined. Why would it refer to `one-star`?

Comment: Because it's the star I wanna click.

Comment: Did you mean to use a click [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/n91z8emf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to try to do it with JavaScript. But you have errors. You have invalid id selectors so you have an error and you are not doing a check correct. To do what you want to do would require JavaScript event handlers.

How to do it with just CSS

```css
label {
  margin: 0;
}

.star-container {
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.star-check {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  -o-appearance: none !important;
  -ms-appearance: none !important;
  appearance: none !important;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url('https://www.worthschools.net/userfiles/197/my%20files/4-stars.jpg?id=29736');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.star-check:checked, .star-check:checked~input {
  background-position: left 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="five-star">How many stars do you give to this product?</label>

<div class="star-container">
  <input type="radio" name="star-check" id="five-star" class="star-check" title="5">
  <input type="radio" name="star-check" id="four-star" class="star-check" title="4">
  <input type="radio" name="star-check" id="three-star" class="star-check" title="3">
  <input type="radio" name="star-check" id="two-star" class="star-check" title="2">
  <input type="radio" name="star-check" id="one-star" class="star-check" title="1">
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `+` instead of `~`!

Comment: @evolutionxbox Copy the snipplet and try that out.... Not sure how an adjacent sibling would work. There is more than one star to fill in...  Your suggestion would probably result in  ☆★★☆☆

Comment: good spot. I had it in my head that all of the radio buttons would be checked. Not sure why